# Power-shell script to return the Service Tag of a server will return service tag = "2"

Tags: windows, powershell, vmware

I am trying to get the Service Tag of a server , so i run the following script:-

```
((Get-VMHost | Get-View).Hardware.SystemInfo.OtherIdentifyingInfo | ?{$_.IdentifierType.Key -like "ServiceTag"}).IdentifierValue[1]
```

but the script returned that the service tag = 2.

so is this correct? as i know the service tag will be a unique number and should contain a combination of characters + integers, something as follow `E1*****2*B****2`.. but will not be a single character as in my case??

Comment: Hint: what does `"E2ABCDE"[1]` produce?

Comment: @JeroenMostert i will get `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.`

Comment: I'm fairly certain all PowerShell versions will produce `2`, because that's the second character of the string. I can only verify with V5 and V2, though. I surmised that `IdentifierValue` is actually a string, and so `IdentifierValue[1]` will give you the second character of that. Try leaving out the `[1]`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert but using the same code on other servers i will get the service tag as `E1*****2*B****2`. So could the same script `((Get-VMHost | Get-View).Hardware.SystemInfo.OtherIdentifyingInfo | ?{$_.IdentifierType.Key -like "ServiceTag"}).IdentifierValue[1]` return 2 different data types (single string and on other scenarios an array of strings)?

Comment: Yes, because PowerShell, helpfully or otherwise, will treat an expression of the form `collection.property` as an instruction to produce an array of `property` by evaluating it over every member of the collection, *or* as just `object.property` if there's just one value, so one expression can produce different types. If you want to ensure `IdentifierValue` is just a single value, use something like `| select -first 1` at the end, or force the results into an array with `@(expression)` before indexing (`@("E2ABCDE")[0]` is `E2ABCDE`). Also, don't forget arrays in PowerShell start at 0, not 1.

Comment: @JeroenMostert also looks like some servers will have 2 service tags.. so for these types of servers my script will work well `IdentifierValue[1]`.. now i got my script from this link http://virtualjalapeno.com/powercli-5-5-wheres-that-dell-service-tag/ so not sure why they are using `IdentifierValue[1]` instead of `IdentifierValue[0]`.. and if a  server has 2 service tags then which one should we use?

Comment: I don't know, I didn't design VMWare's interfaces or Dell's BIOSes. Try checking out the contents of `.Hardware.SystemInfo.OtherIdentifyingInfo` on those servers -- maybe there are other `.IdentifierType.Key` entries that contain `ServiceTag` and are not the actual service tag.